# Getting input box to change url in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi so I have an input box with a button that when click goes to a url. I want it so whatever the user types it goes to the url + the added words in the input box. So lets say its default google.com/search/?q= then when the user types "cat" itll be google.com/search/?q=cat

```html
  <input type= "button" onclick="location.href=\
  'http://www.google.com/search/?q=';"\
   value="Search Google Images"/><br><br>

<br><br> Search item:<input type="text" id="dropdownID"><br><br>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @carambatried all 3 none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the value of the input field with `document.getElementById('dropdownID').value`:

```html
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com/search/?q='+document.getElementById('dropdownID').value" value="Open Testrail Test Plan for Modiciation" />
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>Search item:
<input type="text" id="dropdownID">
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type= "button" onclick="loadUrl()" value="Search Google Images"/>
<br><br><br><br>  Search item:<input type="text" id="dropdownID"><br><br>

<script>
  function loadUrl() {
    location.href = 'http://www.google.com/search/?q=' + document.getElementById('dropdownID').value;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery for that:

https://jsfiddle.net/dqz1pvux/13/

```
<input id="search" type="submit" value="Search Google Images">
<input id="keyword" type="text" value="" placeholder="Type text here">

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#search").click(function(){
       window.open("https://www.google.de/search?q="+document.getElementById('keyword').value+"&biw=1678&bih=790&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNzbLf6OfQAhVD6RQKHZp5BRsQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1.09")
});
});

</script>
```